# Bash history corrupted after power loss

Tags: bash, special-characters, bash-history, data-corruption, character-set

I went to the store and when I came back, I found that I had forgotten to plug in my laptop and It had died from a low battery. When I rebooted, I was surprised to find that my bash history, instead of containing my terminal commands, now looked like this:

```
don@don-Dell-PowerbookBook-777w:~$ �$6:�P!^G����^^B)A|E1����t^E���@=(�|0H�^N�s����+�����C�Ώ)p��s�  pn�ǡ!�ǝ\��"^H�n^M^Rs��$u�^[���^S����![�0^R&^R���@��T���v��8^T^N��^ZJ�O�*�Y$:�A�^[6��jٸ�EIl>��^L�ژ���^^^Xw^T^[��/^Q^Aw       ߨ~�>���s"�6d��^\�U%�a^M/p^P��iޠ��\^M^Z^9��^_l�]*�Ų���J͜��^UK�u�  ����N^S���^G5^B^D�p^^^E��4�&�Qi�^U^?�T^T��-
```

And when I ran `gedit .bash_history`, I got this:

**There was a problem opening the file “/home/dave/.bash_history”.**

**The file you opened has some invalid characters. If you continue editing this file you could corrupt this document. You can also choose another character encoding and try again.**

**Character Encoding: Current Locale(UTF-8)**

and then:

`\D3Q\F6\98ڵ\9B\A8a\9B\97\C7׬\A2\B5\F7\B0,.\B4\FD\E4N\A9͈\FEK\EF蓪*,q\D5HbI\C6!iB\BC\D33\A7\C5\EC\E3\\AE|\D1<%Hx9a\FEI\BE\93f\84\92\C1\AF\B7Ed,6DI<\B5\F9*t\00\DB]PZ\AE\EB\D2\A1e\8C\D4\F8\B4'\8A\CD\00F-\89\CBs\FD;k\CBUv\E1\F8߱y\D0;\BB\9E ůLteE\94\9B\D1\00\E7\CF)\\E51,\9C\81}\E6\96=\C7l\D8v.#s\CE\D5\C2%2\8EZ\93\93<\DD'oIKl.\CC81~\80\DC\F9\A5ȡ@6\E0\DA\F8\92j%\D2;:
b(\BE\F5Dv\86\CD"\A0vCc\EC\A2\F8oP\88\CEG\ED~y\866\B9\AF\BF\BF\DC}\8F\94\CF\DB\C9\D6\DC\D9\E7\E4\DC-\94H\B3\A7\F3\DF\EB\9DS+\E5\C8\81p\8FK\E2\88h\E7f\A8\809\B4\FBo}&aa\FA;\B7q\E8\8D\DE\B5\B5\DE{\EB\A3\F9D\BB\E8\80\A0\FA\F2\F6\A2\BB\C6\D1\CEaN?*H8\91\BD\B83y\FF\BA)\DDl)\87vn\97D\EF\EEOS\F5\FB\B0U`\83\94\E7D\E0:\A3R\94\EC\B9O\D9`wr^D,Q\8B2\C1\9A;l\9Db\86@C*$\D4=\B7v\86ۉ\85\B5\D0g\85\C0{Cb\EA;\ACK\87q\FE\BA\83\B7\86\C0\DF`

For hundreds upon hundreds of lines. Is there anyway to salvage this, or should I just bite the bullet and delete it all?

Comment: But then what do all the charecters mean? I thought this:  `B3\A7\F3\DF\EB\9DS+\E5\C8\81p\8FK\E2\88h\E7f\A8\809\B4`  was hex, it isn't?

Comment: my comments have been condensed into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this every once in a while and usually I just nuke the file because a corrupt file is usually very hard if not impossible to recover.

The problem is that the data appears to have been corrupted.  Which explains random hex code, unicode characters, etc. appearing when you expect readable text.  Data corruption like this is usually irrecoverable, so unless you really need your complete history of commands you've run, you might just want to bite the bullet and erase the file so it can start over.

You can also rename the file to keep the contents if you wish, but the data remains corrupt and likely irrecoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
tr < {original_file} -d '\000' > {backupfile}
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/738854/600169

Also, it appears zsh is better at handling this than bash. It usually gets only one line corrupted. 
I can't find specific sources for lesser corruption in zsh, but it does have better history features overall.

Comment: Just tried it, no dice. :(